# Placing the toolbar above keyboard does not work in iOS 17

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, toolbar, ios17

The next code snippet is an example of the question.

```
import SwiftUI

struct TestingView: View {

  @State var myText = ""
  @State var myText2 = ""

  var body: some View {
     NavigationStack {
        Form {
            Text("Row 1")
            Text("Row 2")
            TextField("Write here", text: $myText)
            TextField("Write here too", text: $myText2)
        }
        .navigationTitle("Testing Toolbar") // delete if you want no title
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .keyboard) {
                Button {
                    print("Button up pressed")
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "chevron.up")
                }

                Button {
                    print("Button down pressed")
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "chevron.down")
                }
                Spacer()
            }
        }
    }

  }
 } 

struct TestingView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
   static var previews: some View {
      TestingView()
   } 
}
```

[image]

It works fine on iOS 16.4 or lower, but not on iOS 17. Any solution for iOS 17?

Comment: Works for me on iPhone (ios-17), but the toolbar does not show on iPad (iPadOS-17) the first time
 I open the App.
 However, closing the App on iPad, then selecting it again shows the toolbar with the "chevrons" that work.
 On MacOS 14.1, Xcode 15.1, tested on real devices (not Previews).

Comment: I'm seeing this too, on iPhone 13 Pro running iOS 17.0.3.

Comment: I have the same issue on my iPhone 13 Pro (works for iOS16.4, but with iOS 17 so far).

Comment: Saw a some posting in the Apple forum about this problem, but no solution yet :(

Comment: Can you provide a link?

Comment: Still an issue with iOS 17.1 :-/

Comment: Same issue!!! did you find any solution?

Comment: How is there no solution to this months and months later?  Seems like a big bug?

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround: adding an empty navigation path to the NavigationStack solved the issue for me (so far).

```
@State var path = NavigationPath()

NavigationStack(path: $path) {
...
}
```

Credits to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75756609/10603205

Comment: It didn't work for me (Xcode 15.1)

Answer (score 0):

It works on iOS 17+ devices and 16.0+ devices & simulators, but not on iOS 17 simulator. This is certainly a bug.