# Buttons not showing up in toolbar keyboard placement in SwiftUI

Tags: button, swiftui, keyboard, toolbar, ios17

I am trying to put a Done button above the keyboard using the toolbar with a keyboard placement. When the app launches and the keyboard opens, the toolbar doesn't show up at all, so the button is not there.

However, if I use a navigation link and navigate to another screen, then come back and tap on a textfield, the button shows up and works as expected. The toolbar also shows up when I quit the app and relaunch it. The problem occurs in iOS 17. It works as expected on iOS 16.

Here's a sample code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var amountField = ""
    @FocusState var keyboardDismiss: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("Screen 2")) {
                    Text("Go to screen 2")
                }
                
                TextField("0.00", text: $amountField)
                    .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                    .focused($keyboardDismiss)
                
            }
            .navigationTitle("Test Keyboard")
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .keyboard) {
                    Spacer()
                    Button("Done") { keyboardDismiss = false }
                }
            }
            
        }
        
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Could not replicate your issue, all works well for me in my tests, on MacOS 14.1, Xcode 15.1, tested on real ios 17 devices (not Previews). It could be different on older systems. The `Done` button is displayed and working to dismiss the keyboard.

Comment: I have got the same issue (see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77238131/placing-the-toolbar-above-keyboard-does-not-work-in-ios-17), but no solution yet. Issue continues to occur with iOS 17.1.